# Clarification about conv.qual#1

Tags: c++, constants, language-lawyer, volatile

[conv.qual#1](http://eel.is/c++draft/conv.qual#1):

> A *qualification-decomposition* of a type `T` is a sequence of *cvi* and *Pi* such that `T` is
>
> *“cv0 P0 cv1 P1 ⋯ cv_n-1 Pn-1 cvn* U” for *n* ≥ 0,
>
> where each *cvi* is a set of cv-qualifiers ([basic.type.qualifier]), and each *Pi* is “pointer to” ([dcl.ptr]), […]
>
> [Example 1: The type denoted by the type-id `const int **` has three qualification-decompositions, taking U as “`int`”, as “pointer to const `int`”, and as “pointer to pointer to `const int`”. — end example]

I don't understand how the description "*“cv0 P0 cv1 P1 ⋯ cv_n-1 Pn-1 cvn* U” for *n* ≥ 0," is compatible with the example.

I mean, the example is for `T == const int**` and a possible decomposition is said to exist for U being `int`. How is that even possible? How can `const int**` (`T`) be written as *cv0 P0 cv1 P1 ⋯ cv_n-1 Pn-1 cvn* `int`?

But more in general, I don't understrand why U is at the end instead of the beginning of that *cv0 P0 cv1 P1 ⋯ cv_n-1 Pn-1 cvn* U_. How can anything starting with, say, `const * volatile * const*` be a type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cv_0 P_0 cv_1 P_1 ⋯ cv_n-1 P_n-1 cv_n U` is not meant to represent the syntactic form of a *type-id* such as `const int**`.

It is meant to represent the formal full-text name for a type after replacing `U`, `P`s and `cv`s.

As the note says the type formed by the type-id `const int**` is formally "*pointer to pointer to `const` `int`*" (and `int const**` would form this same type).

You get this formal name from `cv_0 P_0 cv_1 P_1 ⋯ cv_n-1 P_n-1 cv_n U` by choosing `n = 2` and replacing `U` by `int`, `cv_2` by `const`, `P_1` by "pointer to", `P_0` by "pointer to" and the remaining cv by  .

Comment: So I should have pattern matched `cv_0 P_0 cv_1 P_1 ⋯ cv_n-1 P_n-1 cv_n U` with the English text `non-const pointer to non-const pointer to const int`. I wonder what the advantage in this wording was.

Comment: @Enlico The advantage is that this can actually uniquely identify types. There are generally many ways to form the same type in the language grammar. You need a way to talk about the type itself rather than how specifically it is constructed. E.g. `const int**`, `int const**`, `T**` with `using T = const int;`, etc. are all supposed to refer to the same type and that type needs a name to refer to it when explaining semantics. In many cases you also need to refer to a type without there being any syntax naming the type in the program. It works the same everywhere the standard refers to types.